# Does anyone know how to listen to build events from an already running cctray process, in C#?

Tags: c#, events, triggers, cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I have made a C# application and I am trying to figure out if I can tap into build events of cctray (cruise control tray)? I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I just want to know when my builds fail or succeed (on a client machine) so than my custom C# application may execute a specific set of routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the CruiseControl remote library as a refrence and create an instance of CruiseManagerFactory  and this line will get you the status of all the projects. ServerUri is a string in the format of tcp://ServerName:Port/CruiseManager.rem

```
ProjectStatus[] currentStatuses = managerFactory.GetCruiseManager(ServerUri).GetProjectStatus();
```

in this example I obviously named my instance of CruiseManagerFactory managerFactory.
The array of ProjectStatus then has the current status of all the projects at the address of ServerUri.

Answer (score -1):

Any reason why you can't use your build tool to do that?
e.g. in [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), you can specify the target to be executed when the build fails or succeeds by using [the nant.onfailure and nant.onsuccess properties](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/fundamentals/properties.html#built-in-properties). In the build targets, you could call your C# application via execute tasks.
CruiseControl has [onSuccess and onFailure publishers](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html)... but strangely can't find them in CruiseControl.net.

Comment: The reason is that I work for a Large corporation and getting access to do that on the build servers is hard to do. Instead, we want a client machine to listen to the builds and respond with outside processes.